# How to capture the screen shot of a webpage using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, webdriver

I am trying to capture a screen shot of a webpage using the below mentioned script:

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("D:\\screenshot.jpg"));
```

I am getting the following copyFile is undefined for the method type. Am I missing any package apart from import java.io.File; and import com.sun.jna.platform.FileUtils;.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same approach as you and it works fine for me.

One guess: Check imports in the project:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

That could be causing the error you are getting...

BTW here is my method which works fine:

```
public void takeScreenshot(String nameOfOutputFileIncludingExtension) throws IOException {
    File scrFile = new File("");
    scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)getDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    File destination = new File("target/surefire-reports/" + nameOfOutputFileIncludingExtension);
    System.out.println("Screenshot stored at:" + destination.getAbsolutePath());
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destination);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import should be : `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;`